# Is it possible to use ICON images as background image

Tags: css, extjs, icons

I am trying to use [**ico files**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) to display some CSS data.

Everything works fine it I use **PNG files** (see the top row).

```
.ico-outlet {
    background-image :url('../../../../../img/User_16x16.png') !important;
}
.ico-ogroup {
    background-image :url('../../../../../img/OutletGroup16.ico') !important;
}
```

But the bottom row does not display. Is there any way to get this to work? Or are Icons not allowed.

I am iconifying nodes on an Extjs using **iconCls**. Could the problem lie with Extjs and trying to using icon files for the tree nodes?

Comment: are you sure the path is correct? the one in this fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/2HEpn/

Comment: how are you adding the favicon icon? Have you added it as a resource to the fiddle? or is it a http address to somewhere? I tried http://favicon.ico but it shows nothing

Comment: I just found that fiddle, but by the looks of it, it's just that sites favicon which is just a file you can browse to at http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.ico

Comment: Jsfiddle doesn't use .ico format. The currently used image, atm, is http://jsfiddle.net/img/favicon.png